# R Shiny: How do I call a function that depends on the output of another function?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to return the output of a function call that takes as arguments the output of another function.

Here is my script so far:

```
# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$e_returns <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df_er, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  )

  # Creating the portfolio output
  pf_old_list <- reactive({ mc_func(input$e_world, input$e_eme, input$e_fm, input$e_sc, input$e_danske, input$b_danske, 
                         input$indekser, input$global_ig, input$global_hy, input$emd, input$loans, input$pe, 
                         input$pd, input$infrastruktur, input$ejendomme, input$skov) }) 

  pf_new_list <- reactive({ mc_func(input$new_e_world, input$new_e_eme, input$new_e_fm, input$new_e_sc, input$new_e_danske, input$new_b_danske, 
                         input$new_indekser, input$new_global_ig, input$new_global_hy, input$new_emd, input$new_loans, input$new_pe, 
                         input$new_pd, input$new_infrastruktur, input$new_ejendomme, input$new_skov) })

  pf_key_stats <- reactive({ pretty_output(pf_old_list, pf_new_list) })

  # Outputting the desired figures in a pretty format
  output$pf_key_figures <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(pf_key_stats, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })
}
```

`mc_func` returns a list of 7 numbers.

`pretty_output` returns a dataframe that formats these numbers into a dataframe object. Code looks like this:

```
pretty_output <- function(pf1, pf2) {

  pf1_vect <- as.numeric(unlist(pf1))
  pf2_vect <- as.numeric(unlist(pf2))
  output_data <- data.frame(key_figures, pf1_vect, pf2_vect)
  names(output_data) <- c('xx', 'aa', 'bb')
  return(output_data)
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
reactive({
    pretty_output(pf_old_list, pf_new_list)
}) 
function ()  
 - attr(*, "observable")=Classes 'Observable', 'R6' reactive({     pretty_output(pf_old_list, pf_new_list) }) 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "reactiveExpr" "reactive"
Warning: Error in DT::datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
  [No stack trace available]
```

Thus, I suspect that the object returned by this line `pf_key_stats <- reactive({ pretty_output(pf_old_list, pf_new_list) })` is of a wrong format.

When I run the functions outside of the server, it works perfectly.

Comment: Try `pf_key_stats()` in `renderDataTable`, with the parentheses.

Comment: I get a new error: `Warning: Error in as.numeric: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
  [No stack trace available]`

Comment: The error is probably coming from `pretty_output`. I have updated my question to show how this function is coded.

Comment: Yet missing parentheses: `pretty_output(pf_old_list(), pf_new_list())`. A reactive conductor (`reactive`) is like a function without arguments, you have to put the parentheses to get its output.

Comment: It works now. I just had to wait for the calculation to finish. Thanks!